# Django queryset (filter based on other fields in the same model)

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
class PriceRepository(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='price_repo')

    price = models.DecimalField('price of product', max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)

    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_blank=True, null=True, related_name='price_repo')

    is_default = models.BooleanField()
```

This is my model class. I want to create a queryset such that I pick a price, if a location is specified and if such record doesn't exists for a product, I want to pick the price with is_default set.

It is given that there will always be one default price.

`PriceRepository.objects.filter(location__id=1)` returns records with prices for `location.id = 1`. I want to return default price for all the products present in `PriceRepository`
, if `location.id = 1` is missing

How do I approach this problem?

Solution:
After inputs from Roman Yakubovich,

```
query_set = PriceRepository.objects.filter(product=interested_product)
                                   .annotate(wished_price=Case(When(location=self.location, then=F('price')),
                                              When(is_default=True, then=F('price')),
                                              default=Value(-1),
                                              output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)))
                                   .filter(wished_price__gt=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution based on [Case expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) (can't test it now, so there could be some mistakes):

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, F, DecimalField

PriceRepository.objects.annotate(wished_price=Case(
    When(location__id=1, then=F('price')), 
    default=Value(default_price), 
    output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2))
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your direction helped me. I designed query set as below

`query_set = PriceRepository.objects.filter(product=interested_product)
           .annotate(wished_price=Case(When(location=self.location, then=F('price')),
                           When(is_default=True, then=F('price')),
                           default=Value(-1),
                           output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)))
                 .filter(wished_price__gt=0)`

Default price exists in the `PriceRepository` itself.